# Unhandled Exception Error c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store a text file into an multidimensional array by getting lines from the file, storing them in variables then adding those variables to the array.

```
string QUESTIONS[3][49];

int x;
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("Questions.txt");

getline(myFile, tempNum);
questionNum = stoi(tempNum);

for (int x = 0; x == 49; x++)
{
getline(myFile, line1);
getline(myFile, line2);
getline(myFile, line3);
getline(myFile, line4);
getline(myFile, tempNum);
correctAns = stoi(tempNum);

QUESTIONS[x][0] = line1;
QUESTIONS[x][1] = line2;
QUESTIONS[x][2] = line3;
QUESTIONS[x][3] = line4;

x++;
}
```

Unhandled exception at 0x0FB231CA (msvcr120d.dll) in Ass1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Liam. You need to review your knowledge of for loops. You got the loop condition wrong and you're incrementing `x` twice per iteration.

Comment: First, I don't see how that loop executes *anything*. The condition `x == 49` will not be true before the first iteration can even begin, and will break. Second (and much worse), you're indexing a `[3][49]` as if it is a `[50][4]`.

Comment: Thanks guys, fixed what you said and changed the loop and not getting that error, thanks.

Comment: WhozCraig is right - your indices are back the front - as a tip, you could catch exceptions that would tell you this if you used `QUESTIONS.at(x).at(0)` at least until you'd developed reasonable trust in your code (and coding abilities).

Answer (score 4):

I think a solution could be:

```
string QUESTIONS[50][4];

int x;
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("Questions.txt");

getline(myFile, tempNum);
questionNum = stoi(tempNum);

for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
{
getline(myFile, line1);
getline(myFile, line2);
getline(myFile, line3);
getline(myFile, line4);
getline(myFile, tempNum);
correctAns = stoi(tempNum);

QUESTIONS[x][0] = line1;
QUESTIONS[x][1] = line2;
QUESTIONS[x][2] = line3;
QUESTIONS[x][3] = line4;

}
```

You have increase x twice and the string array was no declared in the right order.